# For the electric field due to an infinite plane sheet of charge, does the result violate coulomb's law or not?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

Can anyone please tell me whether it violates Coulomb's law or not ? I know that Coulomb's Law is

$$F=\frac{(Q_1*Q_2)}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r^2}$$

and that the electric field for charge on an infinite plane sheet is $$E=\frac{Q}{(2\varepsilon_0)}$$ But how to get the answer that I cannot understand.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you asking how to reconcile the two equations or are you merely asking if Coulomb's Law still holds in this scenario ?

Comment: In what way do you think it might violate Coulomb's Law? Coulomb's Law applies for point charges, an infinite sheet of charge is not a point charge.

Comment: @HsMjstyMstdn I am asking that whether Coulomb's law holds good for the expression of infinite plane sheet of charge or not?

Comment: You get the equation for the planar sheet using coulomb law. Coulomb law is for point charges, so you have to consider all the points in the planar sheet separately and add them. You need to know calculus in order to do this.

Comment: Coulomb's Law applies to point charges only.  So it is not "good for" (it does not apply) to a sheet of charge.  Your expression for the sheet of charge is incorrect, by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the electric field $\vec{E}$ is constant (=position independent) for an infinite 2D sheet of constant charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126101/why-the-electric-field-vece-is-constant-position-independent-for-an-infi)

Answer (score 1):

You are under a misapprehension. Coulomb's Law holds for calculating the force a charge exerts on another. Your second equation looks like the electric field due to an infinitely wide, charged plane sheet but it's not quite correct. It should be

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0}$$ where $\sigma$ is the charge density of the plane.

This equation of usually comes from Gauss' Law, not Coulomb's Law, although you can get one from the other. I assume your confusion stems from the fact that the electric field doesn't change no matter what your distance to the plane sheet is and while this is counter-intuitive, it has to do with the dimensionality of space and the "infinite-ness" of your plane sheet.

In other words, the electric field doesn't change when you're *close enough* to a **wide enough** plane sheet. If you integrate all forces between a charge at a distance from the plate and the charge density of the plate, you will find the same thing. For an in depth, step-by-step derivation, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zu2gomaDqnM&t=1304s).

Answer (score -1):

It is very important to note that the magnitude of electric field for a body with uniform charge distribution can easily be found using Gauss Law.

This Gauss law can easily(well maybe not that easy) be derived from Coulomb's Law.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htjxMwHKuyI)

So its pretty clear that the expression for electric field for an infinitely long charged sheet is true with respect to Coulombs Law.